# Return type of lambda function pointer

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I have boost::function pointer's stored in a std::map. These point to lambda functions. How can i obtain the return type of these?

```
#include "main.h"
#include <typeinfo>

typedef std::map<std::string,boost::function<int (A*)>> str_func_map;

int main()
{
    str_func_map mapping;

    mapping["One"] = [](A *a) {return a->one();};
    mapping["Two"] = [](A *a) {return a->two();};
    mapping["B_Nine"] = [](A *a) {return a->getB().nine();};

    A aa = A();
    A* a = &aa;

    for (str_func_map::iterator i = mapping.begin(); i != mapping.end(); i++)
    {
        std::cout<< i->first << std::endl;
        std::cout<< (i->second)(a) << std::endl;
        typedef decltype(i->second) type; //How can I print out the return type of 
        //the function pointer???


    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: erm isn't it always int?

Answer (score 1):

`boost::function` (and `std::function` as well) have a nested typedef `return_type`. So just use that:

```
typedef decltype(i)::return_type TheReturnType;

// or indeed

typedef str_func_map::mapped_type::return_type TheReturnType;
```

Of course, in your case, that will be `int`.

Comment: I'm wondering if they want to print out the 'type'. In which case, they would have to demangle the typeid;

(in gcc this is done https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)